# напомните функцию в пайтоне

Tags: python

подскажите функцию  которая выдаёт True если обнаруживает конец строки, пример:

```
for i in string:
   if  i != пробел or обнаружился конец строки
```

я записываю в список слова из строки, но последнее слово он не видит так как там нет пробела

UPD. решено

использовать  `split` действительно удобнее чем то, как пытался я

Comment: Нет такого. Просто после цикла выполните определенные действия

Comment: Я либо не понимаю чего хочет автор, либо я вижу попытку придумать `split`

Comment: Если хотите перебирать слова в строке, то просто используйте `for word in string.split():`